# Casting subentities between each other

Tags: java, jpa

I have a following model:

```
abstract Article {id, name, text}

final NewspaperArticle { printDate } extends Article

final ScientificArticle { quotations, publicationDate } extends Article

final ... { ... } extends Article
```

I wonder how I could achieve casting the final entities between each other, so that the common fields of Article superclass would be set and the different fields would stay null. Something like:

```
ScientificArticle scientificArticle = ...;
NewspaperArticle newspaperArticle = new NewspaperArticle();
newspaperArticle.copyOf(scientificArticle);
```

Is it possible to cast it or I will have to use reflection?

Comment: Design-wise, casting between NewspaperArticle and ScientificArticle is not valid according to Liskov's substitution principle (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). A NewspaperArticle is a specific type of Article and therefore it could substitute one. You cannot claim the same however for the final entities.

Comment: I agree it might not be "correct", but I need to achieve it somehow.

Comment: I have found out that it is quite good practice to often think of composition (representing common parts of many classes by an own class of which they get an object), in rare cases of inheritance (if you use inheritance prematurely you can get serious problems later as I have seen in a company) and never of reflection (you don't need reflection for regular programming, just for "meta programming").

Comment: @Vojtech in my opinion if you need to do such a thing then you have a design issue. i would suggest thinking your implementation over. anyway, i'm not qualifying for an answer here, i'm just giving you my own perspective on the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question in short: No, you can't cast an object to another class. You may only cast to supertypes of the object's real class. (A class is also a supertype of itself.)

You could, however, use composition instead of inheritance:

```
interface Article { ArticleData getArticleData(); }

final ArticleData {id, name, text}

final NewspaperArticle { articleData, printDate } implements Article

final ScientificArticle { articleData, quotations, publicationDate } implements Article

final ... { articleData, ... } implements Article
```

Then you could add a constructor like `NewspaperArticle(Article createFrom)` to each class which sets the article data field and leaves the others null:

```
class NewspaperArticle {
  ArticleData articleData;
  Date printDate = null;

  NewspaperArticle(Article createFrom) {
    this.articleData = createFrom.getArticleData();
  }
}
```

Your example would then look like:

```
ScientificArticle scientificArticle = ...;
NewspaperArticle newspaperArticle = new NewspaperArticle(scientificArticle);
```

Comment: I did not want to do it this way, becuase once the Article interface changes in future - for example, some column is added - the change might be forgotten in the constructor and the field won't be copied. I wanted to do it somehow "automatically".

Comment: @Vojtěch The field could not be forgotten the way I implemented it. Please have a look at it again: The only place where a field needs to be added is the ArticleData class. Within the constructor, the ArticleData object is used. However, ArticleData needs to be immutable for this to work. Another approach would be to make it Cloneable (see [Object.clone()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone())).

Comment: Ok, my bad, sorry. It is a possibility, but it breaks the current design of my persistent entities :/

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that, because as you said, NewspaperArticle has some information (e.g. fields) that ScientificArictle hasn't. I also don't know how you want to achieve that with reflection. And even if you could, that would be a sign of poor class design, if you have to rely on such things.

Comment: "Foreach Getter if there exist a Setter, use it." - Why should it be poor design? Like this, I can be sure, that I will never forget to add the entity from the class to the "copyOf" method.